# Should I move large files generated by App Engine out of the way?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just exported some database tables from App Engine, to guard against catastrophic loss. All my generated files, (csv, .sql3, bulkloader logs) are still in my app directory.

Then I resumed development and it seemed to be taking forever to upload my updates when I did a

```
appcfg.py update .
```

In fact, I killed the update, as it was taking a long time. So should I move these large generated files out of the way? I like them where they are, because it makes keeping track of them easier, but if it's going to slow down updates, I'm willing to move them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should move them. The appcfg script is going to try to process them and that will slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to modify app.yaml and add them to the ignore list.

Comment: Sorry. Seems to be a false alarm. After an interval of a few hours, I tried again and it update my app in just a couple of minutes.